# Returning a dataset / array from a Generic Inquiry in BLC / graph code

Tags: acumatica

I need to obtain a dataset or array of the results provided by a Generic Inquiry inside of BLC / graph logic.

I've been given the following as an example, but this obviously only returns a count.

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
public PXAction<SOOrder> Test;
[PXButton]
[PXUIField]
protected void test()
{
    var dataGraph = PXGenericInqGrph.CreateInstance("GI000010");
    if (dataGraph != null)
    {
        var count = dataGraph.Views["Results"].SelectMulti().Count;
    }
}
}
```

When I use an index in the returned variable, I don't get anything that resembles a row of the actual data in the GI, for example:

```
dataGraph.Views["Results"].SelectMulti()[0]
```

This doesn't return the actual data.  I've tried the several methods / properties provided by the dataGraph.Views["Results"] object, but none give me the results I need.

Is there a method or property that simply returns a dataset or array of the actual results of the Generic Inquiry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following custom button I developed for Non-Stock Items will call the specified Generic Inquiry, update its parameter value and retrieve all result rows and corresponding field results without needing to know the specific DAC.

```
public class NonStockItemMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<NonStockItemMaint>
    {
        #region Buttons
        public PXAction<InventoryItem> RunSummary;

        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Run Summary")]
        public virtual IEnumerable runSummary(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            InventoryItem item = Base.Item.Current;

            GIDesign design = PXSelectReadonly<GIDesign, Where<GIDesign.name, Equal<Required<GIDesign.name>>>>.Select(this.Base, "ItemTrans");
            if (design != null)
            {
                PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this.Base, delegate ()
                {
                    //Creates Generic Inquiry Graph for the specified inquiry
                    PXGenericInqGrph graph = PXGenericInqGrph.CreateInstance(design.DesignID.Value);

                    if (design != null)
                    {
                        //Sets parameter value
                        graph.Caches[typeof(GenericFilter)].SetValueExt(graph.Filter.Current, "Item", item.InventoryCD);

                        //Loops through each returned result row of Generic Inquiry
                        foreach (GenericResult resultRow in graph.Views["Results"].SelectMulti())
                        {
                            //Loops through objects returned from one - not an object per field
                            foreach (string key in resultRow.Values.Keys)
                            {
                                //Loops through list of each object and the fields we need values from for each data key
                                foreach (GIResult resultMap in PXSelectReadonly<GIResult, Where<GIResult.designID, Equal<Required<GIResult.designID>>, And<GIResult.objectName, Equal<Required<GIResult.objectName>>>>>.Select(graph, new object[] { design.DesignID.Value, key }))
                                {
                                    //retrieves field value from data object specified
                                    var result = graph.Caches[resultRow.Values[key].GetType()].GetValue(resultRow.Values[key], resultMap.Field);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            return adapter.Get();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Tables referenced in Generic Inquiry :
[image]

Data fields to retrieve from the inquiry :

[image]

Parameters being populated :

[image]

Value being retrieved :

[image]

Comment: Thanks much for that - can you tell me how to send a parameter to the GI?

Comment: I updated my response to make clear where that occurs, the code is graph.Caches[typeof(GenericFilter)].SetValueExt(graph.Filter.Current, "Item", item.InventoryCD); where "Item" is the parameter. If this revolves your issue marking the answer as accepted would be helpful.

Comment: I believe that did it, Joshua.  Thanks so much!   As an aside, Acumatica support engineers said that this was not possible (getting the results of a Generic Inquiry inside BLC code).  You rock.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of the results. Each list element will contain the records involved with 1 row of the GI result (each joined table). Only those fields included in the GI will have values I believe.

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> Test;
[PXButton]
[PXUIField]
protected void test()
{
    // Using "Invoiced Items" (GI000008) GI in 2017R2
    var dataGraph = PXGenericInqGrph.CreateInstance("GI000008");
    if (dataGraph == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var resultList = dataGraph.Results.Select().FirstTableItems.ToList();

    foreach (GenericResult genericResult in resultList)
    {
        //  Note: not all values are pulled into the DAC, only those used in the query
        var arInvoice = GetDac<PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoice>(genericResult);
        var arTran = GetDac<PX.Objects.AR.ARTran>(genericResult);
        var customer = GetDac<PX.Objects.AR.Customer>(genericResult);
        var customerClass = GetDac<PX.Objects.AR.Customer>(genericResult);
        var address = GetDac<PX.Objects.AR.Customer>(genericResult);
        var bAccount = GetDac<PX.Objects.CR.BAccount>(genericResult);
        var inventoryItem = GetDac<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem>(genericResult);

        var formulaValues = genericResult.Values.Last();
    }
}

protected virtual T GetDac<T>(GenericResult genericResult) where T : class, PX.Data.IBqlTable
{
    // Example: 
    //var customer = (PX.Objects.AR.Customer)genericResult.Values["Customer"]
    return (T)(genericResult?.Values != null && 
        genericResult.Values.ContainsKey(typeof(T).Name)
        ? genericResult.Values[typeof(T).Name]
        : null);
}
```

Comment: - PMF
I've tried that - but I get the same thing I get with SelectMulti.  Here are the results:

 ?resultList[0]

 Records (1): GLTran[0]: {GL Transaction[module:GL, batchNbr:GL013332, lineNbr:23]}

This result makes no sense to me.  I'm looking for the actual data from the GI.

Comment: is this a custom GI or a standard GI provided with Acumatica? I tested on a custom GI i have and my list had my expected 22 items in the list. (tested in 2017R2)

Comment: Also, just to confirm, are you able to get valid results on another GI?

Comment: I'm using a custom GI - but I guess my problem I have is how to actually access the members of the list that's returned.  It seems to be an array, but I don't know the syntax to drill down into the actual values in a code line (I can see them if I use the immediate window and click down into the cascading members).  The members don't exist, and I can't use an index, either numeric or string.

Comment: updated answer. This will find you the individual row objects, however not all values are filled in. you will need to know which field value you need. I wonder if there is a call that can be set in the GI graph to capture all data values.

Comment: I guess what it boils down to, is since it's simple to return a multi-dimensional array in a web service call to a GI,  can this also be done in the BLC?   I don't know ahead of time what the GI's base tables are, and so I can't cast the result to that specific DAC.   I need to just obtain an array that I can get results out of based on indexes only

Comment: sounds like we need to better answer this question is how do we know the returned values from the resulting DACs. I have not tried this yet but adding as a comment in case someone else has tried this specific request before. I am sure we can get the list of columns from the result then get the values from the DACs automatically without having to know the DACs you need. I can try later when i have some time to see if i can get this to work.

Comment: Thanks so much Brendan!  ;D